# Connecting Android tablet to Web Service

Tags: php, android, web-services, wamp

I am trying to connect my tablet to a Web Service that I have in my WAMP Server. I have tried doing everything I've read and had no luck connecting it. The web service reads data from SQL Server and shows it in the application. For now, that is all it needs to do. I have a code that I followed from a tutorial so that I could do the ASync Task, but it still doesn't help. Here is the code:

```
package com.example.secondtestsqlserver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    String pid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .detectAll()
        .penaltyLog()
        .penaltyDialog()
        .build());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void clickSend(View view) {
        new TestWS().execute();
    }
    class TestWS extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                "http://170.54.162.239:80/webservice.php", "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Record Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt("success");
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray("master"); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            EditText txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
                            EditText txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTest);

                            // display product data in EditText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString("test"));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString("name"));
//                            Log.e("Checking", product.getString("test"));
//                            Log.e("Checking", product.getString("name"));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the JSONParser Class

```
package com.example.secondtestsqlserver;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET method
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e("Unsupported Encoding", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("Client Protocol", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IO Exception", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            Log.e("JSON Parser", json);
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

And this is the PHP Web Service

```
<?php
    $serverName = "localhost\SQLExpress";
    $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"Android");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

/*  if ($conn)
    {
        echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }*/

    $query = "SELECT * FROM AndroidTest;";

    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
    $master = array();
    if (sqlsrv_num_rows($result)) {
        $master["record"] = array();
        while ($posts = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $record = array();
            $record["test"] = $posts["test"];
            $record["name"] = $posts["name"];

            array_push($master["record"], $record);
        }
        $master["success"] = 1;
    }
    else {
        $master["success"] = 0;
        $master["message"] = "No products found";
    }
    header('Content-trype: application/json');
    echo json_encode($master);
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```

I do know for a fact that the PHP is right, since it is giving me the data I want, but the application doesn't work in my tablet, nor does it work in the emulator. Also, note that on the MainActivity class, I use the StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(). This is because I read that when I get the onNetworkMainThreadException, this usually fixes the problem even though it is unsafe. I was planning to change it, of course, after I find out why I can't connect. The error is this one:

```
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://170.54.162.239:80 refused
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at com.example.secondtestsqlserver.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:62)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at com.example.secondtestsqlserver.MainActivity$TestWS$1.run(MainActivity.java:75)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /170.54.162.239 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  ... 17 more
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/IO Exception(25431):  ... 22 more
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/Buffer Error(25431): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/JSON Parser(25431): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at com.example.secondtestsqlserver.MainActivity$TestWS$1.run(MainActivity.java:79)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-21 09:03:45.049: E/AndroidRuntime(25431):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I would not be asking if I hadn't already tried everything I found in here and everything I found on the internet. I need to make this work soon, so please any help you can give me will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the root cause:

```
failed to connect to /170.54.162.239 (port 80): connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
```

So make sure, your service is running there and can be reached from your tablet. (Maybe try to fetch a HTML page from the server to make sure you have connectivity)

Comment: Well, that is the computer's IP Address. I have my laptop and my tablet connected to a LAN I made in a cellphone (no internet), and I am trying to access the computer's local host through there. I have no idea if I'm doing this right, I'm new at this and I'm trying to learn how it works.

Comment: The IP address does not look like its on a LAN. I do not really understand how you have setup your network. Do you have a firewall running on the server?

Comment: I am doing local tests, you probably noticed since I am using SQL Express. My cellphone acts as a router. Both my tablet and my laptop are connected to my cellphone via wireless. Somehow, I need my tablet to find the path to my Web Service (which is located in my WAMP Server local host) which is obviously in my laptop. These are my work conditions right now, as this is something I'm doing at work. I don't know if what I want to do is possible though.

Comment: Ok, it was a very stupid mistake on my part. I was using the IP Address of the Local Network and not the Wireless Network IP. I have access now but it is still not accessing the WAMP Server, as if it was turned off.